# javascript - check first char of username

Tags: javascript, html

English isn't my primary language,so I'll try to do my best to explain myself...I need to, using javascript, check the first letter of input username of the user,and see if it's between A-Z or a-z . If not it will delete the string the the user entered.  Why isn't the code working?

```
function UsernameRegisterVaildation()
{
    var username = document.getElementById("usernameRegister");
    var x = false;
    var y = false;
    if (x.CharAt(0) >= 'A' && x.CharAt(0) <= 'Z')
        x = true;

    if (y.CharAt(0) >= 'a' && y.CharAt(0) <= 'z')
        y = true;

    if (!x || !y)
    {
        alert("WRONG USERNAME");
    }
}
```

and here's the input:

```
        Username: <input type="text" id="usernameRegister" name="UserNameRegister" onchange="UsernameRegisterVaildation();"/>
```

Comment: You should be checking `username.value.charAt(0)...`, not `x` itself.

Comment: The method is `charAt` not `CharAt`

Comment: Why do you think it's "not working"? What happens?

Answer (score 5):

It's `charAt`, not `CharAt`. Also, you've got a reference to the element that holds the username, not the username itself - get the `value` property.

You may as well just use one regular expression, though:

```
if(!/^[a-z]/i.test(username.value)) {
    ...
}
```